# MongoDB: кракозябры вместо русского языка

Tags: node.js, кодировка, mongodb, csv, mongoose

### Ситуация

При создании документа в **MongoDB (Mongoose)** заполняю поля русским либо английским языком. Когда вывожу эти поля в консоли **(cmd)** через **mongod.exe** + **mongo.exe** вместо русского языка вижу `������`. Эти же проблемы возникают с приложением написанным на **node.js**.

### Вопрос

Что может быть не так с русским языком в **MongoDB** и как это исправить?

### PS

Пользуюсь модулем **fast-csv** который читает и парсит **csv-файлы (excel)**. С его помощью читаю свой **csv-файл** с русским языком и заполняю поля распарсеным текстом.

Comment: В какой кодировке входной csv файл? Возможно нужно перекодировать из win1251 в utf-8

Comment: Текст перегружен форматированием, тяжело читать. [Когда стоит использовать внутристрочное выделение для кода?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1328/181472)

Comment: А вот структура хорошая, за нее плюс. )

Comment: Мне кажется, проблема не с бд, а с консолью, и кракозябры из-за неё. У меня в mongo (из коробки) на маке и на убунту русские буквы поддерживаются прекрасно.